# How to connect to redis-ha cluster in Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: redis, kubernetes, containers, cluster-computing, kube-dns

So I recently installed stable/redis-ha cluster (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/redis-ha) on my G-Cloud based kubernetes cluster. The cluster was installed as a "Headless Service" without a ClusterIP.  There are 3 pods that make up this cluster one of which is elected master.

The cluster has installed with no issues and can be accessed via redis-cli from my local pc (after port-forwarding with kubectl).

The output from the cluster install provided me with DNS name for the cluster.  Because the service is a headless I am using the following DNS Name

port_name.port_protocol.svc.namespace.svc.cluster.local (As specified by the documentation)

When attempting to connect I get the following error:

> "redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to
>   port_name.port_protocol.svc.namespace.svc.cluster.local :6379. Name does not
>   resolve."

This is not working.

Not sure what to do here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

the DNS appears to be incorrect. it should be in the below format

```
<redis-service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:6379

say, redis service name is redis and namespace is default then it should be
redis.default.svc.cluster.local:6379
```

you can also use pod dns, like below

```
<redis-pod-name>.<redis-service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:6379

say, redis pod name is redis-0 and redis service name is redis and namespace is default then it should be
redis-0.redis.default.svc.cluster.local:6379
```

assuming the service port is same as container port and that is 6379

Comment: So this is a head less service... forgot to mention that.

I am currently using <redis-service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:6379

Because it's a headless service I also tried (as recommended here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#srv-records)

<port_name>.<port_protocol>.<redis-service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:6379

Which has also been unsuccessful.

Comment: what do you see in pod logs? does it say redis server is started and is accepting connections?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant. Just enhance the chart similar to other charts to support NodePort, e.g. rabbitmq-ha so that you can use any node ip and configured node port if you want to access redis from outside the cluster.